# How to update to other table when inserted into one table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql. One is `create_load_test` and another is`load_test`. I am inserting data into `create_load_test` table via html form. It is get updating.
There are 9 columns in `create_load_test` and 3 columns in `load_test`.

I want to update id and load_test column values of 'load_test' table, When a row is inserted in `create_load_test` table via html form.

How to do this? I know only basics of mysql.
Can you help me to solve this?

**create_load_test:**

[image]

**load_test table:**

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Are you using any programming language or just MySQL?

Comment: I don't know how to implement this, I searched to solve this I didn't get how to do this.

Comment: use `TRIGGER` for this

Comment: Create_load_test table is get updating.There is now problem with this, But, how to fetch id and loadtest column from that table and insert into load_test table.

Comment: @Amol Raje, Hi, I know , I have to use trigger but, For this I am not getting how to use this one.I am begginer in mysql.

Comment: Something to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used like this, now it is working fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggered_from_createload 
    BEFORE insert ON create_load_test
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO load_test
    SET load_test.id = new.id,
     load_test.loadtest = new.loadtest;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this using trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_A` AFTER UPDATE ON `A` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE B
    SET  username = NEW.username
       , password = NEW.password
       , email = NEW.email
    WHERE id = NEW.id;    
END $$
```